# JS - Adding arrays to an array with variable name manipulation using for

Tags: javascript, arrays, for-loop, concatenation

So I have some arrays (in reality I have about 30-40):

```
var p1  = ["John", "bio", "john.png"];
var p2  = ["Kate", "bio", "kate.png"];
var p3  = ["Mary", "bio", "mary.png"];
```

which have the respective information for each person I want to use in my HTML.

I want to add each of these arrays to another array to have a final result of:

```
var people = [["John", "bio", "john.png"], 
              ["Kate", "bio", "kate.png"], 
              ["Mary", "bio", "mary.png"]];
```

Is there a way of adding all these `p1` , `p2`, `p3` arrays to the `people` array using a for loop?

I tried this:

```
for (var i = 1; i <= 30; i++) {
    var toPush = "p" + i;
    people.push(toPush);
}
```

But obviously this just creates and pushes strings into the array. How can I get around this?

Thanks!

Comment: Why are you not adding initializing them in a `people` array in the first place?  `var people = [["John", "bio", "john.jpg"], ["Kate", "bio", "kate.jpg"], etc];`

Comment: Just use `people = [p1, p2, p3]`. If you don't like to type out thirty different variable names, don't use 30 variables in the first place.

Answer (score 3):

You should start with a people array instead of creating individual variables for each array create your arrays like this:

```
var people = new Array();
people.push(["John", "bio", "john.png"]);
people.push(["Kate", "bio", "kate.png"]);
```

etc...

Comment: Personally, I’d use `var people = [];` over `var people = new Array();`

Comment: You're right, I didn't realize how pointless what I was doing was until I read this.. :D Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can use javascript eval for this purpose but it's not recommended. For issues with eval() please see https://stackoverflow.com/a/86580/4810628

```js
function l(){
  var p1 = ["John", "bio", "john.png"];
  var p2 = ["Kate", "bio", "kate.png"];
  var p3 = ["Mary", "bio", "mary.png"];



  var people = [
    ["John", "bio", "john.png"],
    ["Kate", "bio", "kate.png"],
    ["Mary", "bio", "mary.png"]
  ];
  alert("length before adding elements:"+people.length);

  for (i = 1; i <= 3; i++)

  {
    people.push(eval("p" + i));
  }

  alert("length after elements added:"+people.length);

}
```

```html
<body onload="return l()">
  
  </body>
```

Comment: Why is there jQuery code in this answer? No `jquery` tag is present on the question, it could be confusing to the poster. You're also using a dangerous `eval` here...

Comment: @Cᴏʀʏ thanks for the info. here it says it's open to injection http://stackoverflow.com/a/86580/4810628  can you please add few words how an injection attack can happen with eval?

Comment: Honestly, for this trivial example, there's technically no danger, but as using it at all is generally frowned upon, it's better to opt for code that excludes it altogether.

Answer (score 0):

```
function ArrayList()
{
  var people=[];
  people.push(["John", "bio", "john.png"]);
  people.push(["Kate", "bio", "kate.png"]);
  people.push(["Mary", "bio", "mary.png"]);

    for(var j=0;j<people.length;j++)
    {
        console.log( people[j] );
        alert(people[j]);
    }
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/ys9jptsn/